# What is the adjective for "supersedure" or "primacy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, legalese

Is there an *adjective* that can express the concept of a law that supersedes other laws?

I would prefer a single adjective that has legal connotations, although a present participle will suffice. The phrases *supreme law* and *overruling law* approximate this concept, but *supreme* merely seems to indicate significance, and *overruling* implies direct contradiction, rather than "displacement in favor of another" as *supersedure* indicates (the laws do not run completely contrary to one another, but one is more appropriate and takes precedent). Also, the phrases *the law which has primacy over other laws* and *the law which supersedes other laws* are too wordy and awkward for my intended usage in a paper about a certain contentious Supreme Court decision.

Is there an adjectival form of "primacy" or "supersedure", or another adjective which accurately describes this legal usage? Here is the sort of context in which I intend to use such an adjective:

> The ruling demonstrated disregard for the ________ constitution/law/legal right.

Comment: Generally the law that applies to a given situation is said to be _the **applicable** law_.

Comment: Would it not work to simply say, “The ruling demonstrated disregard for the _superseding_ constitution/law/legal right.”? (I suppose _supersedentary_ is out of the question…)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet In my opinion, _superseding_ in this context implies that the law is being superseded, not doing the superseding.

Comment: @TheodoreBroda Hmm. That sounds rather unintuitive. I would have thought that would be the _superseded_ law … but maybe it’s a bit like _substitute_ where you’re never really quite sure which is coming and which is going?

Comment: Which Supreme Court case? Surely either the majority opinion  or the dissenting opinion will contain exactly the word you are looking for.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Exactly, the past and present participle could have different meanings to different people. Also, some people could assume that _superseding_ is a gerund being used attributively, equivalent to _supersedence law_. It just feels awkward to me. However, I _do_ like _supersessory_; being a true adjective, these same potential limitations do not apply.

Comment: @200_success After reading both the majority and dissenting opinions for this particular action, I can assure you that neither contains the word, surprisingly. It seems that the justices constructed their sentences to use verbs like _taking precedence_ or _supersede_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would imagine the simplest way to do it would be simply *superseding*; but since you’re looking for more legalistic-sounding terms, there is:

> The ruling demonstrated disregard for the ***supersessory*** constitution/law/legal right.

The OED defines [*supersessory*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/301430) (or its synonym, [*supersessive*](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/194506)) as:

> Having the quality or character of supersession; taking the place of something or someone displaced

– and gives a citation that appears to me (who am not very well-versed in US law, I should note!) to be quite parallel to what you’re looking for:

> His decrees are always in the form of rescripts, which conclude with a general supercessory clause, *contrariis quibuscunque non obstantibus*. (*The Monthly Review* (London), Sept. 205, 1789)

Comment: Both words are great options; they fit my definition well, are used in legal contexts (according to your sources), and are cognates of _supersede_. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider the term **[preemption](http://research.lawyers.com/glossary/preemption.html)**

> a doctrine in conflicts of law: when a superior government (as of a state) has undertaken to regulate a subject its laws supersede those of an inferior government (as of a municipality).
>
> According to the doctrine of preemption, federal law supersedes state law when federal law is in conflict with a state law on a subject or when there is congressional intent to regulate a subject to the exclusion of the states. Federal preemption is based on the supremacy clause of the U.S. Constitution and is closely related to the powers granted Congress in the commerce clause.

The adjectival form is *preemptive*.

Comment: This seems quite accurate, except that it deals specifically with ‘automatic’ supersedure based on a hierarchy, which is narrower than what is asked (if I’m understanding things right). The very different, but much more common, meaning of _preemptive_ (as in _preemptive action_ or _go on a preemptive strike_) could confuse matters, though. I would not immediately know whether a _preemptive law_ was one that superseded another, or one that was passed in order to preemptive forestall something.

Comment: Excellent! I particularly like the established legal usage, and the  word fits the context unambiguously, the other meaning of _pre-emptive_ notwithstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps 'overarching' ? Not strictly related to legal matters of course.

Comment: While the term you offer may be helpful, a definition and a source of that definition are generally needed to make an acceptable answer for this type of question.

Comment: _Overarching_ is a pretty good choice, but unfortunately it indicates _influence_ of other rulings/legislation on a broad scale, rather than _taking precedence_ over a single other verdict/law. Anyway, thanks for sharing your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with '[ultimate](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ultimate)' as in the 'ultimate authority.'

Alternatively, '[fundamental](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fundamental)' may be more in line with your example sentence.

Comment: Thanks! _Ultimate_ works well, implying that it is the _final_ source of authority on a subject. However, _ultimate_ does share some limitations with _supreme_, as people may assume it means _optimal_ rather than _having primacy_.